# Проверка на авторизацию flask

Tags: python, flask, авторизация

Сайт микро-блог на flask. Есть авторизация для админа. Если вход правильный, то скидывает на страницы, где можно редактировать посты, удалять и создавать новые.

Так вот, если я перейду по ссылке на эти закрытые для обычных пользователей страницы, то они все равно откроются (например, та же страница admin_panel ниже - я могу на нее зайти просто по ссылке). Не могу нагуглить, поэтому пишу здесь. Можно как то сделать условие, типо: если вход совершен, то перейти на страницу можно, если пользователь не вошел, то скидывает на страницу для авторизации? (и этот код я просто смогу вставить во все необходимые функции или страницы, если это так работает)

Буду очень рад какой нибудь ссылке, если у вас есть, куску кода, который я адаптирую под себя или просто объяснению.

Вот примерные куски кода, которые у меня есть.

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        Login = request.form.get('Login')
        Password = request.form.get('Password')

        db_lp = sqlite3.connect('login_password.db')
        cursor_db = db_lp.cursor()
        cursor_db.execute(('''SELECT password FROM passwords
                                           WHERE login = '{}';
                                           ''').format(Login))
        pas = cursor_db.fetchall()

        cursor_db.close()
        try:
            if pas[0][0] != Password:
                return render_template('admin/auth_bad.html', tab_title='Ошибка Входа')
        except:
            return render_template('admin/auth_bad.html', tab_title='Ошибка Входа')

        db_lp.close()

        return redirect(url_for('admin_panel'))

    return render_template('admin/authorization.html', tab_title='Авторизация')


@app.route('/admin_panel')
def admin_panel():
    all_posts = databases.get_all_posts()
    posts = all_posts[0:10]
    page_data = get_page_data('all_posts')

    return render_template('admin/admin_index.html', posts=posts, page=page_data,
                    admin_section='admin_panel',
                    tab_title='Админская панель')
```

Comment: Основной подход в аутентификации это выдача фронт-энду различных токенов (например jwt). Данный токен отправляется с фронт-энда в заголовках запроса, бэк-энд проверяет токен, и если он корректный - выдаёт данные/страницу. Поищите статьи по ключевым словам "oauth2 flask".

Comment: спасибо большое. написал бы ответом, я бы поставил правильным.